# web scraping this scheme

Tags: html, excel, web-scraping, vba

**EDIT**

Web page: https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=RDS%2FA

I am trying to extract a bit of stock information from the html below, using an HTMLDocument (pretty sure its an anchored href element, but..). I thought I had it with

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(158).innerText
```

but it turns out that some stocks will have the text at position 158, others 159. I also tried

```
doc.getElementById("busDesc-more")
```

and

```
 doc.getElementsByTagName("h3")
```

Both seem to get me in the right neighborhood but I don't know where to go from there.

How would an experienced scraper scrape this?

**HTML**

```html
<DIV id=busDesc>
<P>Google Inc., a technology company, builds products and provides services to organize the information. The company offers Google Search, which provides information online; Knowledge Graph that allows to search for things, people, or places, as well…</P>
<DIV class=spacing-div_10X0></DIV><A href="javascript:viewMore('busDesc');"><IMG src="https://scs.fidelity.com/common/application/etf/14.10/images/plus_blue.gif"> View more </A></DIV>
<DIV id=busDesc-more class=hidden>
<P>Google Inc., a technology company, builds products and provides services to organize the information. The company offers Google Search, which provides information online; Knowledge Graph that allows to search for things, people, or places, as well as builds systems that recognize speech and understand natural language; Google Now, which provides information to users when they need it; and Product Listing Ads that offer product image, price, and merchant information. It also provides AdWords, an auction-based advertising program; AdSense, which enables Websites that are part of the Google Network to deliver ads; Google Display, a display advertising network; DoubleClick Ad Exchange, a marketplace for the trading display ad space; and YouTube that offers video, interactive, and other ad formats. In addition, the company offers Android, an open source mobile software platform; hardware products, including Chromebook, Chrome, Chromecast, and Nexus devices; Google+ to share things online with people; Google Play, a cloud-based digital entertainment store for apps, music, books, and movies; Google Drive, a place for users to create, share, collaborate, and keep their stuff; and Google Wallet, a virtual wallet for in-store contactless payments. Further, it provides Google Apps, which include Gmail, Calendar, and Google Sites that are built for people to work anywhere, anytime, on any device without loss of security or control; Google Maps Application Programming Interface; and Google Earth Enterprise, a software solution for imagery and data visualization. Additionally, the company offers Google App Engine, a platform as a service offering; Google Cloud Storage; Google BigQuery for real time analytics; Google Cloud SQL for structured query language; and Google Compute Engine, an infrastructure as a service platform. It also offers mobile wireless devices, and related products and services. Google Inc. was founded in 1998 and is headquartered in Mountain View, California.</P>
<DIV class=spacing-div_10X0></DIV><A href="javascript:viewLess('busDesc');"><IMG src="https://scs.fidelity.com/common/application/etf/14.10/images/minus_blue.gif"> View less </A></DIV>
<DIV class=spacing-div_15X0></DIV>
<DIV class=dark-grey-hr>
<DIV class=hr-for-ie></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=spacing-div_13X0></DIV>
<DIV class=sub-heading>
<H3>Sector (GICS®)</H3><SPAN class=right><A href="http://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/sectors/sectors_in_market.jhtml?tab=learn&amp;sector=45">Information Technology</A></SPAN> </DIV>
<DIV class=clear-both></DIV>
<DIV class=spacing-div_13X0></DIV>
<DIV class=dark-grey-hr>
<DIV class=hr-for-ie></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=spacing-div_13X0></DIV>
<DIV class=sub-heading>
<H3>Industry (GICS®)</H3><SPAN class=right><A href="http://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/sectors/industries.jhtml?tab=learn&amp;industry=451010">Internet Software &amp; Services</A></SPAN>
```

**GOAL**

get "Information Technology" from

```
<A href="http://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/sectors/sectors_in_market.jhtml?tab=learn&amp;sector=45">Information Technology</A>
```

** **FINAL UPDATE** **

based on Kerry's answer (and Matteo's edit) I have the code below, which works consistently for almost 200 stocks:

```
Private Function GetAnchorTextForSubHeading(ByRef headerNbr As Integer, ByRef doc As HTMLDocument) As String

   Dim tags As IHTMLElementCollection
   Dim anchors As IHTMLElementCollection

   Set tags = doc.getElementsByClassName("sub-heading")
   Set anchors = tags(headerNbr).getElementsByTagName("a")
   GetAnchorTextForSubHeading = anchors(0).innerText
```

End Function

Comment: Could you give us the link to the webpage? It's not very easy to understand the structure like this.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ. See edit at top of post. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it assuming that it is the first .sub-heading classed tag on page.

```
Set tags =  doc.getElementsByClassName("sub-heading")
yourdata = tags(0).getElementsByTagName("A").innerText
```

## update

based on feedback that .sub-heading is not unique changed code to get first instance of .sub-heading and fixed typo in ByID to ByClassName

Comment: Hi Kerry. Yes, that makes sense but there are a bunch of "sub-headings" on the page. AND I accidentally omitted this tag, "<DIV id=busDesc>" from my original snippet (now fixed). Can you show me how to navigate from that tag?

Comment: Is that sub-heading you are looking for always the first one?

Comment: No, it's never the first occurrence. More like the 7th. Worse, afraid the occurrence varies a little depending on the stock. That's why I asked about navigating from the "busDesc" ID.

Comment: Kerry, you were close but your code actually errors unless you get the 0 index for TagName("A"). See my last edit. You got me close enough but does this make sense to you? Cheers

Comment: Yep! I wasn't running it to see, just off top of head. Glad I could help!